# рефлексия,ооп java в 1 букете

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть класс, у класса поле `DBService` - это интефейс. В конструкторе  создается по нотации конкретный инстанс поля( загружается xml файл, в которм есть таг `<DBService> </DBService>` как у значения  нотации, там считывается конкретный класс, по типу как в Spring -Dependacy ingection)

```
public class SessionsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject("DBService")
    protected  final DBService dbService;
    protected final AccountService accountService;

    public  SessionsServlet() {
        this.dbService = (DBService)  Initialize.run("dbService",this);
        accountService = new AccountService(dbService);

    }
```

`Initialize.run("dbService",this)`- на вход поучает имя поля и объект и возвращает объект- экземпляр класса считанный в xml

```
public class Initialize {
    public static Object run(String fieldName, Object o) {

        String className = null;
        try {
            Field field = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("dbService");
            Inject annotation = field.getAnnotation(Inject.class);
            className = xQueryTester.execute(annotation.value());
            if (annotation != null) {

                return Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;

    }
```

Если я наследуюсь от класса `SessionsServlet`

то при  попытке  создать экземпляр вызовется конструктор предка  в нем метод `Initialize.run("dbService",this);`

в нем `Class.forName(className).newInstance();` Нужен один и то-же обьект для всех наследников, может 
даже вылетит  `IllegalAccessException` т.к. поле финальное.

Как всем наследникам расдовать один и то же экземпляр?

Answer (score 2):

Метод `getDeclaredField` не смотрит вверх по иерархии классов. Следовательно, если ты наследуешься от некоего класса, то в его наследнике ты не сможешь достучаться до родительского поля при помощи данного метода, а так как у тебя в коде присутствует

```
 o.getClass()
```

, то именно так и произойдёт. Собственно тебе надо добавить поиск поля вверх по иерархии классов и проблема исчезнет.

---

Однако стоит сказать, что у тебя есть проблемы в построении кода. Передача ссылки на ещё не инициализированный объект, т.е. в конструкторе

```
 this.dbService = (DBService)  Initialize.run("dbService",this);
```

Такое использование `this` может породить проблему утечки памяти. Метод `run` принимает ссылку на объект, однако никаких манипуляций с объектов внутри него не происходит. Лучше заменить тип параметра на `Class<?>`. Архитектура класса `SessionsServlet` выглядит вообще странно. Если ты хочешь инициализировать поле в конструкторе (т.е. из внутри) при помощи операции присвоения, то проведение его анализа выглядит очень противоречиво. DI как раз и предназначен для инициализации полей из вне.

---

Плюс к тому, если ты хочешь использовать один экземпляр класса во всём приложении (т.е. singlton), то тебе надо заменить

```
 return Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

чем-то другим.

Comment: На счет this -согласен, не красиво, на счет getdeclaredfields()-да нужен рекурсивный метод подъема. Если вместо final-использовать static, то поля 1 раз будут проинициализированы?

Comment: @ketchyn если вместо `final` использовать `static`, то поле будет инициализировано столько раз, сколько будет вызываться инициализация. Как вариант можно пометить поле как `static final` и инициализировать его в блоке `static {}`

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в DI фреймворках есть возможность указать на контекст (забавный термин), т.б. жизненный цикл. Будет ли объект единым для одного только реквеста, для каждой инъекции возвращать новый объект или он будет для всего приложения синглтоном и т.п.
Обычно сервисы создаются в корне композиции и имеют жизенный цикл синглтона. Вам нужно либо реализовать такую возможность. Для этого пишут, как правило, свой загрузчик классов - там таким вещам самое место. Или взять готовое решение.
 
Не стоит создавать объекты для иньекций в конструкторе класса, где эта инъекция проводится - это ломает полность смысл инверсии, а класс получается "слишком умным" - должен слишком много знать о приложении и слишком много уметь.
З.Ы. Почему вы не хотите взять готовую имплементацию, есть довольно маленькие и простые ди фреймворки?